# Kotlin Error 'unresolved reference' appears when trying to run Java Code from a Kotlin file

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, kotlinc

Referencing Problem when Java Class is used in Kotlin. There is the Java class `Base32Decoder.java` and code from this class is used in the Kotlin file `hello.kt`.

When I try to run Java code through a Kotlin file, an error occurs because of no reference could be established to the Java class `Base32Decoder`.

Error message:

> hello.kt:4:25: error: unresolved reference: Base32Decoder

`Base32Decoder` Java class can't resolve the reference to it. Since this class is used inside the Kotlin file, the reference needs to work.

Code

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>){
    val Base32Decoder = Base32Decoder()
   val rectangleArea: String = Base32Decoder.base32Decode("JBSWY3DPFQQFO33SNRSCC===")
   println("inside the Kotlin codes:" + rectangleArea)
}
```

How can I reference Java classes when I want to use Java code in Kotlin files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you added the library to the classpath, and have you added the appropriate import in your Kotlin source file?